# Is there a way to share same datagrid between tab items in WPF?

Tags: wpf

Is there any way that two tab items share a datagrid in wpf.
For ex:

```
<TabControl x:Name="tbMain">
<TabItem x:Name="tab1" />
<TabItem x:Name="tab2" />
</TabControl>
```

So what I am meant is, Can tab1 and tab2 have same datagrid, just the values different?

Comment: If they had different values, how could they be the same datagrid?  Can a bit in memory be equal to both 0 and 1 simultaneously?

Comment: Create a new view with the datagrid, place the view in both tabs.

Comment: I'm curious as to why you would want to do that... can you enlighten me?

Comment: DOC,Shreidan I need to create datagrids with many columns say 30, so whenever the user clicks different tabs they see the different values for same columns.

Comment: Khan, sounds a good idea, thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TabItem` is a `ContentControl`, and you can't have the same control in two containers at once.

However you could stick with empty TabItems and the `DataGrid` below and outside the `TabControl`. With a bit of styling of the borders you could make it look like the DataGrid is part of the same control. You can then vary the `DataSource` of the grid based on the currently `SelectedItem` of the `TabControl`.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know why you want that, In WPF `same control cannot be child of different parent` at the same time. But if you want to define your `DataGrid` just once and use it that you can achieve by defining a `ContentTemplate` for your `TabControl` like:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="contentTemplate">
  <Grid>
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding MyItemsSource}"/>
  </Grid>
</DataTemplate>

<TabControl Width="250" Height="300" 
            ContentTemplate="{StaticResource contentTemplate}">
```

Here `DataTemplate` "contentTemplate" will be applied to any `TabItem` which does not have ContentTemplate defined.

The thing to remember here is that `TabItem` `Content` should be set and that Content should contain the Collection property that should serve as `ItemsSource` to your `DataGrid`.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't have the same control in 2 containers, but why not simply have 2 controls bound to the same datasource?  Then in your viewmodel, when the current selected item changes, etc... mirror that to the other control.